# Python - Discord bot command unresponsive

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Login bot: {bot.user}')
 
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi, there!')
 
bot.run('token')
```

When I run the code and type !hello in Discord, nothing happens. What's wrong?

Comment: Enable message content intent to use prefix commands. Both in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and in your code: `intents.message_content = True`

Comment: Also make sure message intents are available in discord developers portal else it will throw error